# weird characters while reading text and binary from a socket's stream in java

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have tried to search for an answer with no luck (both at google and StackOverflow)

I am writing a java program in which a Server and a client can communicate by sending/receiving data and files...

I am sending the files by chunks of 1MB each. To let the client know the number of chunks, I am sending a string line containing `BlockNb=x` where x is the number of chunks, followed by the file.

However when I am reading it from the client, I am receiving instead of this line some weird characters: `ur\u0000\u0002[B¬ó\u0017ø\bTà\u0002\u0000\u0000xp\u0000\u0000\bPï»¿` where `\b` and `\uxxxx` are the representant of their values (I was expecting here `BlockNb=1`)

(written in a clearer way: `ur  [B¬ó ø Tà   xp   Pï»¿` (where the spaces are escaped characters)

here is my code.
server side

```
try (
        ServerSocket welcome = new ServerSocket(6500);
        Socket socket = welcome.accept();
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
    )
    {
        System.out.println("accepted");
        File f = new File("...");  //the file path
        try (
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f)
        )
        {
            long length = f.length();
            byte[] buffer;
            //here I put only the code that was executed
            buffer = new byte[(int) length];
            printWriter.println("BlockNb=1");

            fileInputStream.read(buffer);
            outputStream.writeObject(buffer);

            printWriter.println("}");
        }
    }
```

client side

```
try (
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6500);
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/D/test.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream())
    )
    {
        String msg = scanner.nextLine();  //the weird string was read at this point
        long blockNb = Long.parseLong(msg.split("BlockNb=", 2)[1]);
        byte[] file = (byte[]) inputStream.readObject();
        fileOutputStream.write(file);
    }
```

P.S.: When I removed the last 3 lines (only) from the server side everything went normal. I've received `BlockNb=1` as expected. So the problem only appeared when there was a mix of two types of data/two types of outputStreams

English is my third language so forgive me in case of bad grammar or word misuse

Edit: The main problem here was that I forgot to flush the streams. However when I flushed the streams I started to receive EOFException (that I could avoid in debugging if I applied an ordering for read/write - there was a kind of synchronization problem) so I used QuickSilver's solution which worked in addition to flush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using two different objects to write to and read from the same stream.  Try just using the ObjectOutputStream on the server side and the ObjectInputStream on the client side.  Handle your strings the same way you handle your buffers:

Server: `outputStream.writeObject("BlockNb=1");`

Client: `String blockNbStr = inputStream.readObject();`

Comment: I found my problem: I forgot to flush the streams. but I got another problem. in case I couldn't find it I will use your solution. thanks (I didn't know that you can send a `String` via `writeObject` I thought it was for `Serializable` only and `String` is not)

Comment: String is serializable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html